# What is causing openssl signature verefication preform 5 times faster then GPG?

Tags: openssl, rsa, public-key-encryption, gnupg

I have a machine with openssl(1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018) and GPG(gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.0-unknown) and a 130mb file.

I created RSA key pair with openssl and GPG same key length same RSA algorithm.

I signed the file with openssl and got a signature file and then signed it with GPG(detached signature) and got a signature fie.

When I time the signature verification with openssl I get 2.4 seconds and when I do the same with GPG I get 10-12 seconds.

What might cause such a big time difference?

Comment: Unless your computer is like 30 years old, that's insane. The time for actual RSA verify operation (modexp d) up to 4096 (the highest supported by GPG, and highest normally used with OpenSSL) should be about a millisecond, not several seconds. If the file being signed/verified is large (gigabytes) (and not cached) it might take seconds to read, but that should be the same for both programs, or close. Conceivably hashing large data could also be slow depending on which hash you use; try hashing alone (without sign or verify) in openssl.

Comment: Regarding the machine, it is dedicated to be used for embedded development with ARMv7 Processor rev 10 (v7l) with 1Gb of memory(220mb free) and 1GB SD card used as storage. ruining Linux.

I used sha256 for the measurements I did for GPG and openssl signature verification.

I did another measurement for sh256sum terminal command and got 3.568s, when executing openssl dgst -sha256 i got 2.465s

Comment: Try it with a small file. It might be inefficient file reading on your RPI.